# How can I select ONLY THE INDEX COLUMN in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a dataframe like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxhbQ.jpg)

Using the following code, I can convert a column to a list.

```
a = df["price1"]
a_list = []
a_list = a.values.tolist()
```

I would like to do same thing for the index column but It's not possible.

ex.
indexlist = [2020-01-02, 2020-01-03, 2020-01-06, 2020-01-07, 2020-01-08]

Would you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Did you try putting `pandas get index` into a search engine?

Answer (score 1):

Simply access the `DataFrame`'s `index` attribute with `df.index`

Comment: So embarrassed... Thanks a lot!

Comment: No need for that! We all start somewhere. I've only been doing this less than four years myself @KJH. Please accept this answer if it solves your problem (check the checkbox below the vote counter)